# Age of Empires II HD on intranet

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

Is it possible to play Age of Empires II HD on an intranet? Is there a way I can specify the host ip? My version is the Steam one. Let me know if further details are needed. Thanks.

Comment: Knowing why you need to do this would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you begin a multiplayer game where all the players are on the same network, AoE2 will automatically run it as a LAN game.

However, Age of Empires HD multiplayer requires a Steam connection to run. If your network has no outside connection or you are trying to avoid a firewall on a public network, you won't be able to create the game.

This also means you can't share copies of AoE. You still need one account per player.